# How to perform clustering on Word2Vec

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis, data-mining, word2vec

I have a semi-structured dataset, each row pertains to a single user:

```
id, skills
0,"java, python, sql"
1,"java, python, spark, html"
2, "business management, communication"
```

Why semi-structured is because the followings skills can only be selected from a list of 580 unique values.

My goal is to cluster users, or find similar users based on similar skillsets. I have tried using a Word2Vec model, which gives me very good results to identify similar skillsets - For eg.

```
model.most_similar(["Data Science"])
```

gives me -

```
[('Data Mining', 0.9249375462532043),
 ('Data Visualization', 0.9111810922622681),
 ('Big Data', 0.8253220319747925),...
```

This gives me a very good model for identifying **individual** skills and not group of skills. how do I make use of the vector provided from the Word2Vec model to successfully cluster groups of similar users?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/jeffd23/visualizing-word-vectors-with-t-sne

Answer (score 12):

You need to vectorize you strings using your Word2Vec model. 
You can make it possible like this:

```
model = KeyedVectors.load("path/to/your/model") 
w2v_vectors = model.wv.vectors # here you load vectors for each word in your model
w2v_indices = {word: model.wv.vocab[word].index for word in model.wv.vocab} # here you load indices - with whom you can find an index of the particular word in your model
```

Then you can use is in this way:

```
def vectorize(line): 
    words = []
    for word in line: # line - iterable, for example list of tokens 
        try:
            w2v_idx = w2v_indices[word]
        except KeyError: # if you does not have a vector for this word in your w2v model, continue 
            continue
        words.append(w2v_vectors[w2v_idx])
        if words: 
            words = np.asarray(words)
            min_vec = words.min(axis=0)
            max_vec = words.max(axis=0)
            return np.concatenate((min_vec, max_vec))
        if not words:
            return None
```

Then you receive a vector, which represents your line (document, etc).

After you received all your vectors for each of the lines, you need to cluster, you can use DBSCAN from sklearn for clustering.

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
dbscan = DBSCAN(metric='cosine', eps=0.07, min_samples=3) # you can change these parameters, given just for example 
cluster_labels = dbscan.fit_predict(X) # where X - is your matrix, where each row corresponds to one document (line) from the docs, you need to cluster
```

Good luck!

Comment: I really like this approach, and it works well for clustering documents (here: user skill tags) with a limited set of vocabulary words. Just a word of caution for future readers: It didn't work at all for me with documents which are composed of whole sentences :-(

Comment: Method question: is vectorizing the strings/Word2Vec even needed? Could you just hot-code the skills and cluster based off of that?

Comment: @Dasha What is the reason for getting the `min_vec` and `max_vec` and concatenating them?

Comment: @JeffParker TFIDF would work too, but I believe vectorization lets you use similar words rather than exact words.

Comment: I think there is bug in `vectorise(..)` here, shouldn't we be checking `if len(words):` not `if words` and after we have finished iterating over all the `word in line` ?